# Python DHT22 code error

Tags: python

I am working on a Raspberry Pi DHT22 Humidity monitor.
This is my code: [pastebin.com/vHGCgjd2](http://pastebin.com/vHGCgjd2)
And when I run this code, this is the output:

Humidity is Critical! (Too high) Current humidity: 45.2 %

And I have no idea why it says that "Humidity is CRITICAL!", because the humidity is 45.2% and 45.2 is not higher than 75%.
Please help.

Comment: What is the physical setup of your system?

Comment: Please put code inline - don't make people visit another website to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create string `hum` and then you compare string with integer (65 and 75) so you get wrong result. You have to compare number `t` (or maybe `h`) with integer (65 and 75).